# Regex inconsistency when using parentheses

Tags: r, regex

Can anyone possibly help me understand why the following:

```
require(stringr)
x = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
str_detect(x, 'dog')
#> [1] TRUE
str_detect(x, '(?=dog)')
#> [1] TRUE
str_detect(x, '(?=quick)(?=dog)') # fails why?
#> [1] FALSE
str_detect(x, '(?=quick)(?=.*dog)')
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Lookaheads like `(?=quick)` match immediately before the content in the lookahead. The point where `(?=quick)` matches doesn't also have `dog` immediately after it. What did you want your regex to mean?

Comment: Your fourth regex is the one you want to logically assert that `dog` appears anywhere after `quick`.

Comment: `'(?=quick)(?=.*dog)'` = `'(?=quick.*dog)'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), *look ahead* and *look behind*:

> are zero-length assertions; They do not consume characters in the
>   string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.

So the regex `(?=quick)(?=dog)` will firstly match with `(?=quick)`:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
   ^^  # this position
```

And since it doesn't consume characters, the position stays right before *quick* after the match, and continue to match the next pattern `(?=dog)` which fails because this is not true, actually you will never find a position that is followed by both `quick` and `dog`;

You will find this works if one of the patterns is the prefix of the other, like `quick` and `qui`:

```
x = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
str_detect(x, '(?=quick)(?=qui)')
# [1] TRUE
```

---

`(?=quick)(?=.*dog)` on the other hand tries to find `(?=.*dog)` at the position after matching `(?=quick)`:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
   ^^  # this position
```

Which assert `TRUE` since `quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` can match `.*dog`.

Comment: Thanks Psidom. I'm trying to achieve an AND statement so this works.